# Trying to split on ":" and "," in Python, but failing with ValueError

Tags: python, split

I have a file that I'm reading in and splitting and pushing into a dictionary.  I keep getting an error and I think its because the street addresses contain a comma (,).

Here is my file contents:

```
axe99:315 W. 115th Street, Apt. 11B:New York:NY:10027
jab44:23 Rivington Street, Apt. 3R:New York:NY:10002
ap172:19 Boxer Rd.:New York:NY:10005
jb23:115 Karas Dr.:Jersey City:NJ:07127
jb29:119 Xylon Dr.:Jersey City:NJ:07127
ak9:234 Main Street:Philadelphia:PA:08990
```

Here is my code:

```
f2data = open('ex1.txt')
for line in f2data:
    print line.strip().split(':')
    city_dict = dict(item.split(':') for item in line.strip('\n').split(','))
    print city_dict
```

It keeps throwing this error:

```
['jk43', '23 Marfield Lane', 'Plainview', 'NY', '10023']

city_dict = dict(item.split(':') for item in line.strip('\n').split(','))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required
```

---

I'm new to Python and really have no idea what this error means, any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change `f2data = open('ex1.txt')` into `f2data = open('ex1.txt').readlines()` and give it another try. Also, format your code. Impossible to read as it is.

Comment: I don't think that will fix this problem.

Comment: @Bos, there is no need for `readlines()` here

Comment: What is the desired result for city_dict?

Comment: @bos, thanks for the help but it did not work -- "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

Comment: @gnibbler , my goal is quite simple, i want to take the city and make it the key, and count how many times each city occurs and make that my value

Comment: I'm sure it is quite simple, but can you clarify what is the city? Is it the last 3 colon separated fields?

Comment: @gnibbler it's either New York, Jersey City or Philadelphia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to push a list with 5 items into a dictionary constructor when it only takes two items (in the dict constructor python thinks you are using):

here is a list of possible constructors

```
dict(one=1, two=2)
dict({'one': 1, 'two': 2})
dict(zip(('one', 'two'), (1, 2)))
dict([['two', 2], ['one', 1]])
```

taken from [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

you will need to split your string differently or find a better way of formatting your data.
If you are reading from a `csv` file, refer to Michael Hoffman's answer, which is the correct way to read from a csv.

If not, please specify what you are doing and why.

---

EDIT: Goal added, answer updated

for input:

```
axe99:315 W. 115th Street, Apt. 11B:New York:NY:10027
jab44:23 Rivington Street, Apt. 3R:New York:NY:10002
ap172:19 Boxer Rd.:New York:NY:10005
jb23:115 Karas Dr.:Jersey City:NJ:07127
jb29:119 Xylon Dr.:Jersey City:NJ:07127
ak9:234 Main Street:Philadelphia:PA:08990
```

the code:

```
city_dict =  {}
for line in open('ex1.txt'):
    if item.split(':')[3] in city_dict:
        city_dict[item.split(':')[3]] += 1
    else:
        city_dict[item.split(':')[3]] = 1

print (city_dict)
```

will output what you desire:

`{'NY': 3, 'NJ': 2, 'PA': 1}`

Comment: my goal is quite simple, i want to take the city and make it the key, and count how many times each city occurs and make that my value

Comment: thanks very much ,exactly what i was looking to do - just had to change the id 3 to 2 for city match

Comment: Glad it was what you were looking for, could you please mark this as an answer so people know this question has been answered? It helps me too :).

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `dict` from a list like this, you need a list of 2-element lists (or tuples). For example:

```
my_dict = dict([['axe99', 'New York'], ['jab44', 'New York']])
```

This corresponds to a list of key/value pairs. The error you are getting is because one of the lists in the list you are passing in has five elements, and not two.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Python2.7

```
from collections import Counter
with open('ex1.txt') as f2data:
    print Counter(tuple(item.split(":")[2:4]) for item in f2data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like this:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import collections
import csv

city_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)

with open('ex1.txt') as f2data:
    reader = csv.reader(f2data, delimiter=":")
    for row in reader:
        city_state = row[2:4]
        city_dict[city_state] += 1

print city_dict
```

**Edit:** change to fit clarified description of problem